# How to make recyclerview' card button click a separate event than card click event itself

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view where each card is clickable.

Now, card has a button, when the user clicks on it, it hit 2 events.
1. parent (card) event.
2. Button event.

How can I disable parent event on button click in the card?

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Order order = orders.get(position);
        holder.txtOrderDatetime.setText(order.getDate());
        holder.txtOrderStatus.setText(String.valueOf(order.getStatus()).toUpperCase());
        holder.btn_pay.setOnClickListener(v ->
                Utility.displayToast("Clicked")
        );
    }
```

Comment: is the card click necessery?

Comment: Yes. That is important and can't be removed.

Comment: I have implemented the same logic but both clicks work separately. Can you show XML hierarchy as well as  the card click action code

Comment: i have also implemented the logic and it works. could you share how you set the listener for the card